# Design a one input ,one output serial 2's complementer....(FSM)

Tags: flipflop

My question:

[image]

State table:

```
 A(t)     input       A(t+1)       output
  0         0            0           0
  0         1            1           1
  1         0            1           1
  1         1            1           0
```

i started by forming 2 states(S0 and S1) since we have only 1 flopflop.At S0 when input=0 hold (output will be equal to 0) otherwise move to the next state(S1),I dont know exactly why the output=1 in this case .Finally,At S1 when input=0 then output=1 and when input =1 then output =0.
I'd like to have an explanation of this problem. My final exam is tomorrow.

Comment: @CamilStaps  i started by forming 2 states(S0 and S1) since we have only 1 flopflop.At S0 when input=0 hold otherwise move to the next state(S1),I dont know exactly why the output=1 in this case .Finally,At S1 when input=0 then output=1 and when input =1 then output =0.

Answer (score 3):

First look at the operation of the D type flip flop

[image]

The sequence starts by a reset so Q = 0

The input to the D-type is made up from the initial output (Q) which is OR'd with the first (LSB) bit of the number you are complimenting (X).

The output Y is XOR'd with Q and X  (00 > 0, 01 >1) as Q is '0' we don't have to consider any other case. **So initially the output at Y will always be the same as input at X** i.e our LSB data bit.

The initial input at 'D' will also be the same as the input at X (X OR '0' = X)

Let's take a number - say 28. In binary this would be 00011100
To change this to its 2's compliment we invert and add 1

```
         00011100 --> 11100011 ---> +1 ----> 11100100
```

So if our circuit works a 00011100 input it will produce a 11100100 output

Start with a reset so that Y = X  (Q = '0')

```
        Q (t+1) =  D (t)
        D is X OR Q 
        Y is X XOR Q
```

**LSB first**

```
       X        Q         D         Y
       0        0         0         0
       0        0         0         0
       1        0         1         1
       1        1         1         0
       1        1         1         0
       0        1         1         1
       0        1         1         1
       0        1         1         1
```

Look at the diagonal relationship between D and Q. Q in the next row (t+1) is simply the value of D in the previous row (at time t). Each time the bit is CLOCKED 't' moves on 1. The rest is simply applying the logic of the connected gates to produce a value.